# How to use $GET with calling a popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button to call a popup and I want to pass a value to the form that will popup. Actually I'm using this:

HTML

```
<a href="cadeiras.php?id=<?=$image['id']?>"> 
    <button name="submit" class="open-form">Open</button>
</a>
```

JS

```
$('.open-form').click(function() {
        $('.form-popup').show();
    });

     $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var container = $(".form-wrapper");
        var form = $(".form-popup");

         if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            form.hide();
        }
    });
```

FORM thats popup

```
div class="form-popup">
 <div class="container form-wrapper">
  <form id="my-form" novalidate="novalidate" action="../../orcamento_process.php">
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="$_GET['id']">
```

**I get the value in the form thats popup but the popup appears and dessapears automatically, how can I solve this?**

Comment: i don't know if this solves your problem, but you are dynamically clicking the open form button and i guess ` $('.form-popup').show();` this does the same job.

plus check if the DOM is loaded before doing running your code, doesn't solve the problem i bet , but its a good pratice . 

$( document ).ready(function(){
//  your code here.
})

Comment: it is not okay to have a <a> tag and a button inside that a tag. A tag it s a button it's self, When you click on him you will make a redirect to that ancor and the pop it will be closing. You need to remove the  a tag and in your onclick method must return false to prevent the button to submit the form/page.